# Can't get correct input for DBSCAN clustersing

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I have a node2vec embedding stored as a .csv file, values are a square symmetric matrix. I have two versions of this, one with node names in the first column and another with node names in the first row. I would like to cluster this data with DBSCAN, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the input right.  I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics

input_file = "node2vec-labels-on-columns.emb"

# for tab delimited use:
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0, delimiter = "\t")

# put the original column names in a python list
original_headers = list(df.columns.values)

emb = df.as_matrix()
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(emb)
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

print("Estimated number of clusters: %d" % n_clusters_)
print("Estimated number of noise points: %d" % n_noise_)
```

This leads to an error:

```
dbscan.py:14: FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.
  emb = df.as_matrix()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbscan.py", line 15, in <module>
    db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(emb)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_dbscan.py", line 312, in fit
    X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 420, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, **check_params)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 73, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 646, in check_array
    allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 100, in _assert_all_finite
    msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I've tried other input methods that lead to the same error. All the tutorials I can find use datasets imported form sklearn so those are of not help figuring out how to read from a file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The error does not come from the fact that you are **reading the dataset from a file** but on the **content** of the dataset.
DBSCAN is meant to be used on numerical data. As stated in the error, it does not support NaNs.

If you are willing to cluster strings or labels, you should find some other model.

Comment: I didn't know NaN means not a number. There should not be nonnumeric characters in that file so I will check it.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it was useful to you ;)